# Create tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have this array:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

How could I append a string 'D' to each element and convert every set as a tuple:

```
lst2=  [('A', 'D'),
          ('B', 'D'),
          ('C', 'D')]
```

Comment: `list2 = [(e, 'D') for e in list]`

Comment: Is the last one supposed to be `('C', 'D')`? And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: `('A', 'D')` isn't a sublist at all. It is a tuple.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do the corrections.

Comment: Another way: `[tuple(x+'D') for x in lst]` (assuming all elements in your list are strings)

Answer (score 5):

Like this, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst  = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lst2 = [(x, 'D') for x in lst]

lst2
=> [('A', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

By the way, it's a bad idea to call a variable `list`, that clashes with a built-in function. I renamed it.

Answer (score 3):

alternative solution is use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list(zip_longest(['A', 'B', 'C'], [], fillvalue='D'))
```

the result wiil be:

```
[('A', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = [(i, 'D') for i in list]
```

(apart from the fact that `list` is a very bad variable name)

Answer (score 1):

Another option using zip:

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
res = list(zip(x,'D'*len(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    list2.append((i, 'D'))
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `product()`:

```
from itertools import product

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']

list(product(lst, 'D'))
# [('A', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```